# How often the application is used

Tags: linux

Good day everyone,

How can I detect application which are rarely used on Linux?

Is there any command or tool that can give me the list of all the application's usage frequency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can give you programs, which you least access:

```
find /usr/bin -type f -exec stat --format '%X :%x %n' {} \; | sort -nr | cut -d: -f2- | tail
```

This is just files. And the oldest date is actually when you last used that program **or** when you updated it.

You did not specify your distribution. On rpm distribution you loop through packages (rpm -qa) and pass list its files (rpm -ql PACKAGE) and then get newest access time from that package (stat --format '%X :%x %n' {} \; | sort -nr | cut -d: -f2- | head) and then print it together as name of "$newest_access $package_name" and pipe it to sort -nr | tail and you have least used packages.